# I want to show the result based on my db column status

Tags: mysql

I have created the database column status . In status columns data   is stored 0 or  1

```
1means=active
0 means=inactive
```

l want to show the data with `status1` first and `status0` second and order by news id desc.

Here is my code:The

```
select *from news where status='1'  or status='0' order by nid desc
```

Here i am getting the result , but i  want to  show what are data with `status1` should be show first then `status0`

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 3):

Several things about your question do not make sense:

- If the status is either 0 or 1, why are you comparing it to 1 and 2?
- If the status is an integer, why are do you use single quotes around the values?

The answer to your question is just to put the keys that you want in the `order by` statement:

```
select n.*
from news n
where n.status in (0, 1) 
order by n.status desc, n.nid desc
```

Comment: Thanks , after implementing your query . Results shows  in this order  in status 1,0,0,0,1,1. I want in this way where status 1 should be displayed first.  I want like this  status 1,1,1,0,0,0 . Your query is responding i hope you understood

Comment: @divyakodeeswaran . . . Those results do not make sense.  The first key in the `order by` is `status`, so all rows with the same status should be together.

Comment: Think this n.status desc , i have maintained in status column , while entering by default it is in status 1. I will make active or inactive using 1 or 0 how does status desc work here

Comment: Thanks it is working .after i changed to order by n.status desc,n.nid desc, it gives the result